# Java: A recursive algorithm (or an iterative alternative)

Tags: java, recursion

I am having a hard time trying to formulate a (recursive) algorithm that analyses all possible combinations of tasks to be executed in a schedule. The idea is that I need to find an alternative schedule. Now, I am told that is can be easily achieved in a recursive algorithm that analyses all possible combinations and picks the cheapest solution.

I do this based on a certain cost of a solution, how I do this is trivial. In my schedule I have two machines, let's call them Machine A and Machine B and a series of jobs to be executed, further divided into current jobs and scheduled jobs.

Input:

```
ScheduledJobs: [Job 1, Job 2, Job 3, ..., Job N] (HashSet)
CurrentJobs: [Job 0, Job 00] (ArrayList)
Machines: [Machine A, Machine B] (ArrayList)
```

Expected outcome in the form of:

```
Hashmap
Machine A: Job0 | Job2 | Job3 | ... 
Machine B: Job00| Job1 | Job4 | Job5 | ...
Unassigned: Job6
```

So we can assign a job either to Machine A or Machine B, or when these cannot be assigned cancel them.

Then the algorithm I have thought of works the following way: I believe I can find the cost of the cheapest combination by stating that the cost of a series is the cost of a job + the cost of its series. Something like:

```
function(job1)
    for each job2 in set
        cost = job1.getCost() + function(job2)
```

In psuedocode:

```
public myObject function(job1, myObject){
    make copies of all input //name this copyOf
    for each job2 in the copyOfScheduledJobs do:
        if job2 can be scheduled after job1 {
            set the expected start time for job1
            cost = job1.getCost() + function(job2, myObject)
            if cost < value { // value is calculated by looping through the entire set and summing by getting getCost()
                 value()
                 add job2 to a list
            }
        } else if (!copyOfCurrentJobs.isEmpty())
            copyOfCurrentJobs.remove(0)
            nextCJ = copyOfCurrentJobs.get(0)
            copyOfCurrentJobs.remove(0)
            cost = cost + function(job2, myObject)
        } else {
            cost = job1.getCost()
        }
    }
    return myObject
}
```

Using this algorithm, I find only one schedule that is definitely not the best one.

My question then is: How could I modify this to get the correct solution? As stated in the comments below, it doesn't have to be a recursive algorithm, but this was the best I could think of.

This has been a little long, but I have tried to explain my problem as thoroughly as possible. Hope you can help!

*edited out excessive information.*

Comment: Does it *have* to be recursive ?

Comment: Well...it doesn't _have_ to be. It was just something that felt more natural

Comment: I do like your question and this is an interesting subject. But I have the impression that at this stage the question is either *too short* (how are costs of disruption and delay calculated? What is a disruption? ...) or *too long* (i.e. you should leave out the context and just show a short, reproducible example with the expected result). So I'd suggest you go for the latter and increase the likelihood of getting a useful answer.

Comment: You are probably right. I will edit it by leaving out the context. Thanks for the sugesstion